# Next.js + FontAwesome "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <i>"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

I can't resolve this warning :

```
react-dom.development.js?ac89:67 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <i> in <a>.
    at i
    at a
    at span
    at footer
    at div
```

Here is the component from which this warning originates:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import Navbar from '../navbar/Navbar';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { initGA, logPageView } from '../../utils/analytics/analytics.js';

export default class Layout extends React.Component<{ title: string }> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.GA_INITIALIZED) {
      initGA();
      window.GA_INITIALIZED = true;
    }
    logPageView();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <Head>
            <title>{this.props.title}</title>
            <link
              rel="shortcut icon"
              type="image/png"
              href="/images/favicon.ico"
            />
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <meta
              name="viewport"
              content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
            />
            <link
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bellota"
              rel="stylesheet"
            />
          </Head>
          <header>{/* <span></span> */}</header>
          <Navbar></Navbar>

          {this.props.children}
          <footer>
            <span>Ricotec @Inc</span>
            <span className="linkedIn">
              <a href="//www.linkedin.com/in/radoslav-marinov-problem-solver/">
                <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-2x"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
          </footer>
          <style jsx global>{`
            * {
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            html,
            body {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
              font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto,
                Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue,
                sans-serif;
            }

            footer {
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              padding: 2em 0;
              align-items: center;
            }

            hr {
              padding: 0;
              border-top: 0;
              border-color: #ccc;
            }

            .fa-linkedin-in {
              color: #0a66c2;
              width: 26px;
            }

            .linkedIn {
              margin: 0 1em;
            }
          `}</style>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Please note that the warning comes from this part:

```html
<a href="//www.linkedin.com/in/radoslav-marinov-problem-solver/">
  <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-2x"></i>
</a>
```

If I replace `className="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-2x"` with `className=""` the warning disappears. Something seems wrong with FontAwesome and Next.js' compatibility.

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: As @brc-dd referred to, I'd recommend you have a read through the official docs on how to [setup Font Awesome with Next.js](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react#nextjs) (direct link to Next.js section).

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves 
Seems things have changed recently

Comment: Thanks @brc-dd - yep it woks this way